# Word choice between before and until

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

1. You cannot harm me before you have strong evidence.
2. You cannot harm me until you have strong evidence.

I think 1. is more natural than 2.
Am I right?

Maybe 2. isn't correct at all.
Is it so?

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct.

However, the first is *slightly* more suited, since 'until' has the connotation that you are *anticipating* to be harmed but that they can only do when they have strong evidence.

Answer (score 0):

At the level of the matrix clause, these two sentences carry much the same semantics.   My native reader's eye doesn't see a reason to prefer one over the other.

The word "before" indicates *at **some** prior point*.   The word "until" indicates *at **every** prior point*.   Because the finite verb of the matrix clause is negated, either of these phrases in this context indicates *at **not any** prior point*.